# Strange encoding in Slackware

Tags: virtual-machine, character-encoding, vmware, slackware, special-characters

I am a student and learning about operating systems, I was modifying a file using vi, when I accidentally did something (I don't remember what) that change the codification/encoding and now this is how I see everything.

[image: this]

That screenshot is while using `vi`, but the problem is system wide. I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

I can delete, everything and reinstall, as it is just a virtual machine but I'd rather learn what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think all you need to do is run `reset`.

If that doesn't help, look to see if you changed any files in `/etc` recently (e.g. `find /etc -mtime -1`) and read the `unicode_start` or `consolechars` man pages.

Answer (score 1):

Another, older way of doing the same thing as `reset`:  `stty sane`